# Identify if a website uses Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As part of a school research, I would like to know if certain websites uses Elasticsearch as their search engine. Is there any way of doing so ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know what search engine is being used internally in a website unless they tell you.

But there are many use cases written in the official [Elastic page](https://www.elastic.co/use-cases). Writing the companies/services that use your product in your official page is a common practice.